# CSS to set the dimensions of a child element depending on the ratio of dimensions of the parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a CSS only solution to have a square child element expand until it either hits the width or height of a responsive parent element.

So, if the parent's height is greater than the width, then the child is limited by the parent's width, and if the parent's width is greater than the height then the child is limited by the height. Red is the child:

[image]
[image]

Basically [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r77kmLqb/1/) (try moving the vertical separator to resize the result pane) without the JS.

Since SO insists on including code, here's the linked fiddle again.

```js
$(window).resize(onResize);
setTimeout(onResize); // queue after rendering

var content = $('.content');
var box = $('.box');

function onResize() {
  var w = content.width();
  var h = content.height();

  if (w > h) {  // limit "box" by height
    box.css('width', h + 'px');
    box.css('padding-bottom', h + 'px');
  } else { // limit "box" by width
    box.css('width', '');
    box.css('padding-bottom', '');
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

body > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}

.box {
  outline: solid 1px darkred;
  background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar"></div><!--
--><div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: just a hunch: instead of `width:100%`, use `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`....

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to change the css of a child depending on a parent.
However you maybe could work with "vh" and "vw" in your case and work with the windows height or width. Another, less flexible solution, would be breakpoints.
The example above can easily made without JS with just using vh. See here what it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/jzsqtcac/

```
<div class="sidebar"></div><!--
--><div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
}

body > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20vw;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

.box {
  outline: solid 1px darkred;
  background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have other elements surrounding `.content` which would break the viewport units approach.